# Mark unstable jenkins builds as failed

Tags: regex, jenkins

I'm using the MultiJob plugin to split my job into phases, as a result it will give the "father" an end result of the worse "child" job

My problem is that junit tests are marked as UNSTABLE if tests fails, resulting in a "yellow" dot, I need them to be marked as Failure resulting in a "red" dot

I tried several approches in order to achive this goal inculding using
 Failure Cause Management and looking for the following regexp .+[jsystem].+\bFAILED\b
and also using Health report amplification factor set to 100 which supposed to cause 1% failing tests scores as 0% health. 5% failing tests scores as 0% health

non of the above seems to help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use text [Text Finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin). Add a post build step and search for something "setting the build status to unstable" or whatever your Jenkins says when becoming yellow. If regexp matches - set to failure.

Comment: found my solution by marking multi phase job to proceed to next step only if the previous one is sucess

Comment: -1 because the plugin specifically states "the reclassification only applies to builds which returned an overall exit status of zero", so I can't downgrade an UNSTABLE to a FAILED